# Remove a sublayout in qt?

Tags: python, qt4, pyqt

In PyQt 4.5, I have a layout inside another layout.  I'd like to remove the sublayout from its parent, and hide it.  I can say `parent_layout.removeItem(child_layout)` to remove the layout from its parent, but it still shows on the widget.  I can't find any way to hide it in one step, as `QLayout` doesn't have a `hide()` method like `QWidget` does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easy solution would be to have an interior widget, not an interior layout.  You could assign the layout you desire to the widget, then just remove/hide the widget when you want to do so.  A good rule of thumb is if you just want to arrange how widgets appear, then use a layout; if you want to hide/show them as a group, use a widget.

Answer (score 1):

With some help from flupke on `#qt`, I came up with:

```
for i in range(0, child_layout.count()):
  child_layout.itemAt(i).widget().hide()
parent_layout.removeItem(child_layout)
```

Which assumes all the child layout's children are widgets.  Is there a simpler solution?